# How can I get a report of all Trello cards from certain list from several boards

Tags: trello, if-this-then-that, automation

I need to generate a daily report of all cards assigned to me that exist on a specific list in several boards. All my boards have the same structure so the naming of the lists is always the same.

The cards might remain in a column for several days, so I cannot rely on (for example) [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=%23Trello) since it fires only when new cards are added and I won't produce any useful event that could fire IFTTT's events.

I'm open to use any kind of web application, service, tool or script.

I'd like it to run without launching command line tools, as Shashank Agrawal proposes. It would be better to have it completely automated using web based stuff, such as Google Spreadsheets scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I finally solved it with a dynamic Google Spreadsheet:

1. Follow instructions about [How to import JSON data into Google Spreadsheets in less than 5 minutes](https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a). This leaves you with an automatic polling spreadsheet.
2. Get your [trello key and secret](https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/).
3. Craft those values in the API URL you exactly want to feed into the `ImportJSON` function of step 1.
4. Set your spreadsheet filters as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

We similarly have to create a weekly report from Trello Cards. So, I've written a simple Groovy script which makes my life easier. Basically, Trello provides a simple way of getting long time access token and then using that token, I'm getting all cards first and then its actions (like comments, movements etc) and dumping the required data as needed.

Comment: So, do you want to just download the links and details of card without any further processing? You can try this Chromo extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-for-trello/nhdelomnagopgaealggpgojkhcafhnin

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that extension. That's exactly what I want (setting a filter for only showing my desired column) but I have dozens of boards to parse, that's the main issue that I'm facing when looking for an fire-and-forget solution!

Comment: Then probably you have to go with a script.

Comment: Any ideas on which could be the simpler to deploy and run?

Comment: You can use a Grails based project which is quick and faster way to build a similar application and can be easily deployed.